# sqlsce connection from visual studio 2013 server explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I am trying to add connection to a sqlsce 4.0 sdf file from visual studio ServerExplorer.
I right click dataconnections, and click "add connection"

The dialog "Choose Data Source" comes up. But in the list of available data sources a SQLS CE is not available.

I tried downloading and installing SSCERuntime (from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17876) But the installation fails with message that I already have a later version of sqlsce installed.

So my questions are:

Why is not the sqlsce datasource available, and how do I get it available?

Since the installation tells me I already have a version of sqlsce installed, shouldn't this mean that a sqlsce datasource should be available in the add connection wizard in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

The runtime and Visual Studio tooling are not the same thing, but you can install my free SQL Server Compact Toolbox to get basic Server Explorer support (enough to be able to use the EDM Wizard)